# Wordament Solver - Data Structure for the Dictionary?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashmap, unordered-map

I am working on implementing a Wordament solver and I'm considering using an unordered_map as the data structure to hold my Dictionary. My problem is I don't  understand how I can search through the map effeciently.

Here is the current implementation using a Vector

```
    string currentWord;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dictionary.size(); i++)//OUTERMOST LOOP CYCLES THROUGH ALL WORDS IN DICT
{
    currentWord = dictionary[i];//TEMPORARILY STORES THE CURRENT WORD IN A STRING"currentWord"
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < currentWord.size(); x++)
    {
        currentWordStack.push(currentWord[x]);
    }//AFTER THIS LINE THE currentWordStack SHOULD HAVE THE WHOLE WORD.

    for (unsigned int z = 0; z < letters.size(); z++)//THIS LOOP WILL EMPTY THE STACK IF THE LETTERS CAN MAKE UP THAT WORD
    {
        if (!currentWordStack.empty()&&letters[z] == currentWordStack.top())
            currentWordStack.pop();
        if (currentWordStack.empty())
            break;
    }
    if (currentWordStack.empty())
    {

        cout << currentWord << "\n \n \n \n \n \n \n ";

    }

    while (!currentWordStack.empty())
        currentWordStack.pop();
}
return 0;
```

}

My data structures class never went over hash tables and maps so this is my first attempt. The dictionary has around 400,000 words I will be adding.

Comment: The point of a hash table is to offer quick lookup by trading your expensive-to-compare key (a string of arbitrary length) with a fast-to-compare approximation (the hash value).  You shouldn't need to loop over the entire structure to find your hash value.

Comment: Also, depending on what your requirements are for your solver, you might consider other data structures as well, such as a trie.